# SQL - Dynamic Fieldname Mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

**Example** Data Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SourceTable]
    (
        [Col1] INT            NOT NULL
      , [Col2] BIGINT         NOT NULL
      , [Col3] VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL
      , [Col4] BIT            NOT NULL
      , [Col5] DATETIME2      NOT NULL
      , [Col6] DECIMAL(18, 6) NOT NULL
      , [Col7] TIMESTAMP      NOT NULL
    ) ;
```

**Goal:**
I've a data table of 25 fields. New fields can be added, old fields can be dropped, or existing fields can be modified (name, datatype, and other properties).

We've 7 departments who can each pick and choose which fields they want to output in a report (through the frontend). Whichever fields a department selects, should be mapped to that department. They should be able to modify their selection anytime they want (i.e. a month later, a new field is added to the table, they can go back and add that field to their selection, deselect an existing field, and etc).

**What is the best way to design this?**

We can have a table dbo.DeptField ( DeptId INT NOT NULL, FieldName sysname NOT NULL) and it would look something like

```
DeptId      FieldName
1               Col1
1               Col3
1               Col5
2               Col1
2               Col2
3               Col6
5               Col1
5               Col2
5               Col3
5               Col4
5               Col5
5               Col6
```

Now let's say an existing field is renamed or dropped (e.g. "Col5" is renamed to "ColNew"). Based on the above sample data, we've two departments already mapped to "Col5". Once the field name is modified in the main table, when report query runs and looks for "Col5" field, it won't find it.

Is this a good db design for such "field picker" task? If not, what can I do to achieve the end goal in a more efficient/scalable way? and If so, what sort of validations can I implement so things don't break at the last stage (exporting reports)?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would really help here, however, the fact that you *want* dynamic columns feels like you have a design flaw already.

Comment: Apologies, sample mapping data was not formatted. Done The field selection for each department can change overtime so the mapping table would have to be updated whenever that happens, if we go with above design.

Comment: Just a quick baised oppinion.  Different departments? Then when each deparment has their own table(s) it could be the most (internal) political correct.  But then you'll need some script that can alter the tables based on metadata.  And a script to alter the views on the tables.  By altering a view, the actual columns that they removed, then don't actually need to be dropped from the table immediately.  Same with changing column names names. It's easier to alter a view.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're suggesting creating a view per department? So whichever field the department picks for their report, that department's view would be updated. If a field in the main table is renamed/dropped, whichever view is selecting these now-removed-or-modified fields would be updated. If this is what you're saying, I like the idea. However, let's say we've thousands of departments (just using "Department" as an example), that would mean we would have 1000's of views. Not sure if it's better than a mapping table when we scale this project to that level which we will :(

Comment: This is going to be a nightmare to manage and query. You are going to have to use dynamic sql for everything when retrieving data. You could easily just join to sys.columns on YourName = sys.columns.name. Then it won't find the missing columns. But it will also exclude columns where the name in the base table was changed and not in your mapping table. You are creating a situation that is extremely brittle to say the least. It will break with even the slightest pressure.

Comment: Yea, that is what I'm afraid of. Is there a better way to design this process to meet the above requirement? I want to make it as hands-off as possible or at least have some basic validations to tackle such issues beforehand.

Comment: Also when I think about it, I don't think dynamically creating views would work out well when upgrading builds in the future via dacpac since during the deployment, it would see those views do not exist in the source (db solution) and so it would just drop them. So we need some way to persist the mapped data.

Comment: You started with various departments needing to customize their reports, but seem to have drifted to having them customize the underlying data. Does that mean Shipping can have a ZIP+4 column that Marketing trims to five digits by truncating the column? Engineering can make it an `int` since they know that leading zeros don't matter. What are they really sharing? How do you recover from an inadvertent deletion of data or columns?

Comment: So I'm just using "department" as an easy name for diff groups. Let's say there're two depts, HR and Sales, and dbo.table is Employee table (diff info about emp). HR would like to pull Col1, 3, and 5 while Sales would like to pull Col1, 2, 3, and 6. When these depts select these fields, they're querying the same source. It's just that they have an option to pick and choose which fields from this table they would like to pull in their report. There's no data conversion per dept. We need a way to store the mapping between the different depts and the fields they want to pull.

Comment: You fully expect the column names to change? e.g. "Col5" is renamed to "ColNew"

Comment: Based on the past experience, it is possible, though not guaranteed (wish it wasn't possible).